# RESTful uri: /rest/course/module/prblem/solution vs /rest/solution

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, backend

I am designing a RESTful interface for somewhat hierarchical data:

```
course > module > problem > solution
```

But I cannot decide what the URL for accessing the "solution" resource should be. These are the two options I am choosing between, for example, to retrieve the solution with globally unique PK=3:

```
/courses/2/modules/5/problems/2/solutions/3
/solutions/3/
```

Any advice on which of the two is preferable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have to come up with URLs I always ask myself (in this context)

*Can a solution resource exist without a problem, module or course?*

Yes -> `/solutions/3`

No -> `/courses/2/modules/5/problems/2/solutions/3`

If a solution needs a problem to exist, i.e. it belongs to a problem, it makes little sense to use the short url.

---

Another way to lok at it:
On the backend, do you need a reference to a problem in order to be able to fetch a solution?

No -> `/solutions/3`

Yes -> `/courses/2/modules/5/problems/2/solutions/3`

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! What about the case where someone has to access all solutions? With the second options they can simply go `GET /solutions` and get all solutions, with the first option...?

Comment: @SteveK The ability to GET all solutions with one request more or less indicates that a solution is a resource that can exist on its own. So then the long url wouldn't make much sense :-) (or you would have to make your backend so that it gathers all courses and all modules and all problems and all solutions that belong to them, but that would be inefficient)